# How to add jtable inside of jscrollpane?

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

i know,how to add table inside of Scrollpane. But i've introduced a loop there which is creating problem so please help me to get rid of this problem (i want to add table inside of scrollpane) it seems like it's working whenever i don't introduce scrollpane but whenever I put table inside of scrollpane, it doesn't work. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;




    public class Simple 
    {
    JScrollPane mainScroll;
    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;
    public Simple()
    {
    frame=new JFrame();
    panel=new JPanel();
    mainScroll=new JScrollPane();
    Object[][] rowData = {};
    Object[] columnNames = { "Sr.No","Subject","Department","Status" };
    JComboBox mainBox=new JComboBox();
    mainBox.addItem("Processed");
    mainBox.addItem("Pending");
    DefaultTableModel listTableModel;
    listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    String main = "" + i;
    listTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { main, "", "" ,"Choose"});
    JTable listTable;
    listTable = new JTable(listTableModel);
    TableColumn StatusColumn=listTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    StatusColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(mainBox));
    mainScroll.add(listTable);

    }


    panel.setLayout(null);
    mainScroll.setBounds(37, 143, 397, 183);


   // mainBox.addItem("Processing");


    frame.add(panel); 
    panel.add(mainScroll);
    frame.setSize(600,600); 
    frame.setVisible(true);


    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    new Simple();
    }
    }
```

Comment: You want to add 1000 tables inside the scrollpane?

Comment: 1000 of rows not table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
mainScroll=new JScrollPane();
...
mainScroll.add(listTable);
```

you need to do this after the loop

```
mainScroll = new JScrollPane(listTable);
```

Addendum 1:

You also need to pull the creation of the JTable outside the loop. Inside the loop only add rows to the table.

The core of the solution is like this:

```
JTable listTable = new JTable(listTableModel);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // add rows to the table
}
mainScroll = new JScrollPane(listTable);
```

Addendum 2 (figured I'd need identifiers)

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Simple {
    JScrollPane mainScroll;
    JPanel panel;
    JFrame frame;

    public Simple() {
        frame=new JFrame();
        panel=new JPanel();
        Object[][] rowData = {};
        Object[] columnNames = { "Sr.No","Subject","Department","Status" };
        JComboBox mainBox=new JComboBox();
        mainBox.addItem("Processed");
        mainBox.addItem("Pending");
        DefaultTableModel listTableModel;
        listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
        JTable listTable = new JTable(listTableModel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            String main = "" + i;
            listTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { main, "", "" ,"Choose"});
            TableColumn StatusColumn=listTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
            StatusColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(mainBox));
        }

        mainScroll = new JScrollPane(listTable);

        panel.setLayout(null);
        mainScroll.setBounds(37, 143, 397, 183);

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(mainScroll);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Simple();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because you also need to pull the creation of the JTable outside the loop.